# c++ on iOS, how to move abstract type variable into thread?

Tags: javascript, c++, ios, multithreading

I'm trying to create a SQLite library/adapter for react-native, using new the JSI bindings. JSI bindings are just a layer on top of Javascript Core (and hermes and maybe V8?) that allow calling c++ directly from javascript.

There is a lot of code which is not very important for the purposes of my problem, but basically, sync calls work fine, but now I'm trying to create a thread to do async work and then resolve a javascript promise.

In the code below I create and return a promise, but then try to spawn a thread to do background work.

```cpp
    auto asyncExecSQL = jsi::Function::createFromHostFunction(
      rt,
      jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(rt, "sequel_asyncExecSQL"),
      1,
      [](jsi::Runtime &rt, const jsi::Value &thisValue, const jsi::Value *args, size_t count) -> jsi::Value {
        jsi::Value promise = rt.global().getPropertyAsFunction(rt, "Promise").callAsConstructor(
          rt,
          jsi::Function::createFromHostFunction(
                                                rt,
                                                jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(rt, "executor"),
                                                2,
                                                [](jsi::Runtime &rt, const jsi::Value &thisValue, const jsi::Value *args, size_t) -> jsi::Value {

            jsi::Function cb = args[0].asObject(rt).asFunction(rt);
            auto resolve = std::make_shared<jsi::Function>(std::move(cb));

            thread t1([rt, resolve] { // ERROR: By-copy capture of value of abstract type 'jsi::Runtime'
                resolve->call(rt, jsi::Value(42));
            });


            return {};
        }));

        return promise;
    });

    rt.global().setProperty(rt, "sequel_asyncExecSQL", move(asyncExecSQL));
```

You can more or less ignore all the jsi:: mumbo-jumbo, it's more less manipulating javascript objects from the c++ side. You can see the `Runtime` object is very important, it is needed to manipulate and create objects.

The problem is, I'm trying to create a thread to execute the fetching code in background, I have no idea of the semantics to move/share the `rt` (Runtime) object into the thread.

Can any one explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working:

```cpp
    auto asyncExecSQL = jsi::Function::createFromHostFunction(
      rt,
      jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(rt, "sequel_asyncExecSQL"),
      1,
      [](jsi::Runtime &rt, const jsi::Value &thisValue, const jsi::Value *args, size_t count) -> jsi::Value {

        string query = args[0].asString(rt).utf8(rt);

        jsi::Value promise = rt.global().getPropertyAsFunction(rt, "Promise").callAsConstructor(
          rt,
          jsi::Function::createFromHostFunction(
                                                rt,
                                                jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(rt, "executor"),
                                                2,
                                                [query](jsi::Runtime &rt, const jsi::Value &thisValue, const jsi::Value *args, size_t) -> jsi::Value {

            thread t1([&rt, &query, resolve{ std::make_shared<jsi::Value>(rt, args[0]) }] {
                cout << "Trying to exec" << query << endl;
                vector<jsi::Object> results = sequel_execute(rt, query);

                auto res = jsi::Array(rt, results.size());
                for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    res.setValueAtIndex(rt, i, move(results[i]));
                }

                resolve->asObject(rt).asFunction(rt).call(rt, res);
            });

            t1.detach();


            return {};
        }));

        return promise;
    });
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Great blog by the way! Hopefully we'll get some decent documentation once turbomodules are officially released.

Comment: For some reason on android though when the promise is resolved the RN thread is not automatically updated: i.e. doing something like §`...().then((value) => setState(value))` is not triggered once the resolve function is called on the c++ side. It is triggered only when the ui is rerendered. It works as expected on ios.

Comment: Actually it is also noticeable on ios if you add `this_thread::sleep(2s)`

Comment: you are better off looking into react-native-mmvk or react-native-background-task from msrousavy, he implemented background tasks differently

Comment: Yeah, I went through his repo. He lost me when he imported the code from the reanimated. So his code just creates an executor but the whole communication between the react and c++ worlds is done by the reanimated library...

Comment: yeah, that is overkill, basically, you have to get an instance of the javascript dispatcher and call your callback from there somehow... sorry I cannot give your more info, not working on RN atm